# Finding a missing number from two lists

Tags: java

**Question:**   Lets say we have two unknown integer lists that contain same numbers. However, one of the lists is missing a number. What is the most effective of finding the missing number?

**My Approach:** Have nested for loops like this:

```
public int findMissing(int [] list1,int [] list2){
   for(int i =0; i < list1.length(); i++){
      for(int j=0; j < list2.length(); j++){ 
          if(list1[i] != list2[j] && j == list2.length()-1) 
          return list2[j]; 
   }
}
return;
```

**Explanation**  compare each item in the second list with every item in the first list. If the you reach at the end of the loop and the number in the second list is missing in the first list, then return that number.

Let me know if there is a better way of doing this. Better in terms of running time.

Comment: Is the order of the lists identical?

Comment: For small lists, you can get away with this. But this will scale poorly as the list sizes grow.

Comment: One question: are all elements in the arrays unique?

Comment: Is the order of elements is important? Do you want to know which element from list is different or which on position they are different?

Comment: the elements are not unique and the order of the element is not important.

Comment: I apologize folks, the elements are unique I just checked again to make sure.

Comment: Hang on, there was one fantastic answer that was deleted. Why is that?

Comment: I was wondering @Stranger by any chance is the answer I put similar to the one that was deleted

Comment: nope, its not the same

Comment: @Stranger I'm guessing they used a hashmap then?

Answer (score 10):

(sum of all the numbers from list1) - (sum of all the numbers from list2) = the number you're looking for.

That is assuming the first list is the one containing the additional number, otherwise return the negative value of that number.

Comment: that doesn't work for lists such as [1 1], [1 2], in which case 2 is only in one list and not in the other

Comment: @bengoesboom - true, but the way I understand the question is that one list have one extra number.

Comment: @bengoesboom your example is not correct. One of the list has one missing element! So they can not have the same size! I think the solution is correct.

Comment: @TomerArazy As the question was asked, it isn't clear. To be safe, I would give a solution that handles these cases correctly.

Comment: As to the negative number problem, it is easy enough. Grab the size of both arrays, len1 and len2; after the calculation is done, the result is the calculation of the result if len1 is greater than len2, minus that number otherwise.

Comment: @fge my solution has no overflows (xor)

Answer (score 10):

A better solution than summing the two lists (which can result in overflow) is XORing the lists and XORing the results together. This solution runs in linear time and cannot overflow.
Here is some code to prove it

```
public class Main {
    public static int missingno(int[]first,int[]second) {
        int xor_val = 0;
        for (int i : first)
            xor_val ^= i;
        for (int i : second)
            xor_val ^= i;
        return xor_val;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]a= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        int[]b = {5,4,6,8,3,2,1};
        System.out.println(missingno(b,a));
    }
}
```

Remember xor is a very versatile operator. It is commutative and associative and can be used to swap variables without a temp.

I would also like to point out that another solution would be to maintain a hashmap(initialized to a number that cannot be in the lists) go through the 1-short list, marking each value as existent, and then go through the full list. If you come upon a value that hasn't been set you have found your missing element. The advantage of this is it tells you the index of the missing element right away.

Comment: +1 It arguably can't get any faster than this and doesn't suffer from possible error conditions.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers sadly it won't get the attention of the other answers, I actually got this in an interview once

Comment: True. You arrived late at the party but avid readers might still pick *(vote)* it up.

Comment: A slight simplification: You don't need two totals; just xor all the values of the two lists together ... the result is the missing number.

Comment: @JimBalter clever didn't notice that, xor definitely most underated operation

Answer (score 3):

If the lists are supposed to be the same, you can just sort them.  Then you won't need to nest loops.  You can check both lists at the same location, and they should be equal.  If not, one of the lists is different (depends on which list you are deeming to be correct.)  The runtime would be linear at that point to check the entire list.